# Spawning game object unity (C#)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I writing simple runner game.

I have game object (quad).

I want it to generate.

I wrote spawnscript:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpawnScript : MonoBehaviour {


    public GameObject[] obj;
    //public GameObject obj;
    public float spawnMin = 1f;
    public float spawnMax = 2f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {


        Spawn();


    }

    void Spawn()

    {
        //for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
          //  Instantiate(obj, new Vector3(i * 2.0f, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
         Instantiate(obj[Random.Range(0, obj.GetLength(0))], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Invoke("Spawn", Random.Range(spawnMin, spawnMax)); 

    }
}
```

But my quad spawning one time.I need it to spawn multiple times.

Where is my problem?

Comment: I think this works but the `GameObjects` are spawned on top of one another, while playing keep looking at `Hierarchy` tab to be absolutely sure.

Comment: Yes , you are right @NikaKasradze

Comment: How I can make it spawning right? @NikaKasradze

Comment: in the `Instantiate()` function you need to change the spawn position (the 2nd argument). `transform.position + Vector3.forward` will spawn along the `Z` axis, `transform.position + Vector3.right` will spawn along `X`, etc.

Comment: Don't works @NikaKasradze

Comment: I think there is no problem here. Please uncomment for loop and start unity, after pause it and take a look editor (Hierarchy). Maybe they are spawning far away from camera.

Answer (score 2):

Use `InvokeRepeating` instead of `Invoke` in `start` event:

```cs
// Invokes the method methodName in time seconds, then repeatedly every   repeatRate seconds.
InvokeRepeating("Spawn", 3, 3);
```

If you do [InvokeRepeating](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html)("Function", 1.0f, 1.0f), it will call Function one second after the InvokeRepeating call and then every one second thereafter.
Hence, you can control the spawn timings.

**Update**

As asked in comments:

You can also cancel `InvokeRepeating` any time by calling below code. [More information here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.CancelInvoke.html).

```cs
CancelInvoke("Spawn");
```

Comment: How would you pause the spawning if the game went into a menu state ?

Comment: Interesting - and do you happen to know when this is called ? For instance prior to update or post latteupdate?

Comment: @Zze you call it your self where you want

Comment: I meant... Say you invoke on start, then when does the repeat function call trigger ?

Comment: second and third parameter of the invokerepeating will tell u

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with code. All GameObjects instantiated same position so you can use code below:

```
public float spawnDistanceFactor = 2f; //Value is your choice. You can change it.
void Spawn() 
{ 
     float startPosX = 0f; // I assume your camera look at 0,0,0 point.
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){ 
         Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(startPosX,0f,0f);
         Instantiate(obj, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity); 
         startPosX+=spawnDistanceFactor;
     }

}
```

It is only moves positions on X axis you can move it x,y,z.

Also

You can use Random function for moving spawn position

```
public float randomMin = 2f;
public float randomMax = 4f;
void Spawn() 
{ 
     float startPosX = 0f; // I assume your camera look at 0,0,0 point.
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){ 
         Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(startPosX,0f,0f);
         Instantiate(obj, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity); 
         float randomX = Random.Range(randomMin,randomMax);
         startPosX+=randomX;
     }

}
```

You can do a lot of things.

For destroying prefabs you can add Destroy script to object (You should create prefab with script) Like:

```
void DestroyObject(){
     Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

or use list to hold pointers to the GameObjects. Like:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;      // For list

private List<GameObject> objectList;
public float randomMin = 2f;
public float randomMax = 4f;

void Start(){
  objectList = new List<GameObject>();
  Spawn();
}
void Spawn() 
{ 
     objectList.Clear();     ///For multiple spawn purpose dont dublicate items.
     float startPosX = 0f; // I assume your camera look at 0,0,0 point.
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){ 
         Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(startPosX,0f,0f);
         GameObject newObject = Instantiate(obj, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject; 
         objectList.Add(newObject);
         float randomX = Random.Range(randomMin,randomMax);
         startPosX+=randomX;
     }
} 

void DestroyObject(){
     for(int i=0;i<objectList.Count;i++){
         Destroy(objectList[i]);
     }
}
```

Comment: Okay. It works. But it generates only prefab. I also have destroyer script , and it not works.

Quad not in Main Camera/

Comment: No it generates 10 cubes. You can change spawnDistanceFactor value maybe 5 etc. If your cube's size 10 you can set spawnDistanceFactor 11 etc.