# Spawning object and Destroing player character

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, unity-game-engine

I writing runner.

I have two problems

I have spawning object (quad).

1) I try to spawn my object many times , but  it spawning once.

My Spawn script:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpawnScript : MonoBehaviour {


    public GameObject[] obj;

    public float spawnMin = 1f;
    public float spawnMax = 2f;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {


        Spawn();


    }


    void Spawn()

    {

         Instantiate(obj[Random.Range(0, obj.GetLength(0))], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Invoke("Spawn", Random.Range(spawnMin, spawnMax)); 

    }
}
```

I try  to make spawning script, like here [Spawning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36257276/spawning-game-object-unity-c/36262312#36262312) but facing second problem

And second problem

2) I have destroyer script, I use it on spawning quad. On first object Player character destroys, on second object it through it.

Destroyer script

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DestroyerScript : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {

        if (other.tag == "Player") {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            Application.LoadLevel(1);
            return;


        }
```

Comment: If you want random spawn intervals, consider using a coroutine.

Comment: Can you provide sample or link, where I can read about this?

Comment: Do not be writing runner.   Just get "runner kit" from asset store and drop in graphics. It takes maybe 1 hour to make an entire "runner" these days.

Answer (score 0):

For the spawning problem, you can use a coroutine.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Spawn());
}

IEnumerator Spawn()
{
    // Instantiate your game objects
    Instantiate(obj[Random.Range(0, obj.GetLength(0))], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

    // Wait for a random time interval
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(spawnMin, spawnMax));
}
```

For the collision problem, my guess is, the quad is destroyed by the player in player's collision script.